# how to change css property using liqid

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

I hope somebody can help me out on this.

I would like to change the color property depending on what the tag "name" is. For example if the tag is "silver" the color of the text should be silver.

I tried to goole it and also checked the shopify documentation but did not fined something useful.

(Tag in the code below is 'Oberstdorf'. Tag and link work just fine)

```
{% if product.tags == 'Oberstdorf' %}
    <style> .product-tag > a {color:red;} </style>
 {% endif %}

     <div class="product-tag"><a href="{{ product.url }}">{{ product.tags }}</a></div>
```

Output: the right tag is displayed above the Prise

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your example you're checking against `product.tags` but that is a comma separeted string of all tags, that wouldn't work if you have more than one tag per product (which normally is the case).

If the number of tags is low and you expect to remain like that (Like bronze, silver, gold) you can do something fast like this: in your css you define classes

```
.gold {
 color: gold;
}
.silver {
  color: grey;
}
.bronze {
  color: red;
}
```

and then in your liquid

```
{% assign tagClass = 'gold' %}
{% if product.tags contains 'silver' %}
   {% assign tagClass = 'silver' %}
{% elsif product.tags contains 'bronze' %}
   {% assign tagClass = 'bronze' %}
{% endif %}
<div class="{{ tagclass }} product-tag">...</div>
```

Even if you have a lot of tags defining the color, you still need to define somewhere the color associated to each tag, I think the better approach is in the css file. But if is not possible you could define that in a metafield inside the shop variable or in the setting data. Like

```
{
  "silver1" : "#00F100",
  "silver2" : "#00F200",
...
}
```

Let's say you have that in the metafields

```
{% assign colors: shop.metafields.space.colors.value %} <!-- .value if you're using the 'json' type -->
{% assign colorStyle = 'color: default;' %}
{% for tag in product.tags %}
 {% if colors[tag] %}
     {% assign colorStylee = colorStyle | replace: 'default', colors[tag] %}
     {% break %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<div style="{{colorStyle}}">...</div>
```

Of course these are just examples, but was just to give you an overview of approaches.